# Is it possible to change the default font on all the docs of every users within a google workspace?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace, google-gsuite

I want all the docs every employee in our company create, be in a uniform font (not Arial or Calibri) and set it as default. Can I do the setting once and for all the users in our google workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is to create a template for the organization and have the users create documents from that template. The administrator should go to https://admin.google.com/ac/appsettings/55656082996/docstemplates to manage template settings.

Comment: Thank you @Aerials. We'll trial on that and see if that's easier than just changing the font from any doc. I'll share here what will work best for us. Cheers